# Trying to programmatically add a SQL Alias to the registry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file

Normally when we spin up a new instance we need to add an alias on one of our boxes so we can easily connect to it through SSMS using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

I have written a batch file which adds the appropriate entry into the registry (it is actually two batch files, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit). I am not sure how to get this to run with parameters though. I know `%1` and `%2` would be for the first two parameters, but when I run this, in the registry it actually puts `%1` and `%2` as the value pair.

if you hardcode hostname and IP Address in place of `%1` and `%2` the batch file works as expected:

```
REGEDIT4

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo]
"%1"="DBMSSOCN,%2,1433"
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could (with appropriate permissions) try to write to the registry with T-SQL:

```
USE [master]
GO

declare @p1 nvarchar(100)
declare @p2 nvarchar(100)

set @p1 = N'HostName'
set @p2 = N'DBMSSOCN,1.2.3.4,1433'

EXEC xp_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo', @p1, REG_SZ, @p2
GO
```

Comment: OP wants to write to *client* machine registry, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter in a batch file, use %%1, %%2, etc